# How to hide a div by clicking a button?

Tags: angularjs, onclick

In my angular.js learning project I want to hide one div and show another when I click a button.
In this code, I'd like the first div to be hidden at the click (or even destroyed?) and the second div to be shown. 
Basically I want the user experience of going from page 1 to page 2 in my app.
How do I make this happen?

Index.html

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="StartpageCtrl">

      <div class="list card" id="startCard" ng-show="showstartCard">
          <div class="item item-image item item-text-wrap">
              Card 1
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list card" id="secondCard" ng-show="showsecondCard">
          <div class="item item-image item item-text-wrap">
              Card 2
          </div>
      </div>

      <button ng-click="hideCard()" class="button button-full button-calm button icon-right ion-chevron-right">
          Start now
      </button>

  </ion-content>
```

controllers.js

```
.controller("StartpageCtrl", funcion($scope){
    $scope.showstartCard = true;
    $scope.showsecondCard = false;

    $scope.hideCard = function() {
        $scope.showstartCard = false;
        $scope.showsecondCard = true;
    };
});
```

When I run the page I see "Card 2" and nothing happens when I click the button.
What I wanted to see was "Card 1" and for it to switch to "Card 2" as I click the button...

---

**Solved**
I had forgotten to add references to controllers.js in the app.js angular.module as well as the script tag in index.html. It works fine now.

Comment: Are you missing ng-controller="StartpageCtrl"?

Comment: +1 @SteveLang. Here is a jsbin with you snippet working just fine Tommy. http://jsbin.com/ripekumutowa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Bema and @SteveLang but I don't quite understand.
Why were you saying I'm missing the ng-controller? I had it in the outer div. But ok, per Bema's example I moved it to the body. 
I looked at your code Bema and I still can't get the same result on my end.

Comment: Your javascript looked liked this:  
`function MainCrtl($scope) {  
      
  $scope.showstartCard = true;  
  $scope.showsecondCard = false;  
  
  $scope.hideCard = function() {  
    $scope.showstartCard = false;  
    $scope.showsecondCard = true;  
  };  
}`

Comment: Mine is in the controllers.js file and looks like this:
`.controller("StartpageCtrl", function($scope){

        $scope.showstartCard = true;
        $scope.showsecondCard = false;

        $scope.hideCard = function() {
            $scope.showstartCard = false;
            $scope.showsecondCard = true;
        };


});`
Is there a difference?

Comment: @Tommy your code looks fine. The only things I could think of are (1) a missing ng-app directive in the html, and (2) a missing reference to controllers.js.

Comment: THANK YOU @SteveLang :)
Yes, I was missing references to controllers.js in both the app.js angular.module and in the script tags of index.html. *doh*

Answer (score 1):

```
Using angular:   
 HTML file:
    <td><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails =! showDetails">Source Doc..</a>
                <div id="mydiv" ng-show="showDetails">
                    <div id="mydiv-container">
                        <div id="mydiv-content">
                            <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails =! showDetails">Close</a>
                            <br>
                            hello
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </td>



    css file:
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #mydiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        left: 100px;
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.95;

    }
    #mydiv-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #mydiv-content {
        width: 70%;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #6089F7;
    }
    a {
        color: #5874BF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #112763;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for toggle, then this code might help as there is no need to have any extra CSS or JS functions needed.

```
<button ng-click="isDetailOpen = !isDetailOpen"
        ng-class="!isDetailOpen ? 'ion-ios-arrow-down' : 'ion-ios-arrow-up'"
        class="button button-clear button-positive icon-right">
  <span ng-show="!isDetailOpen">More Detail</span>
  <span ng-show="isDetailOpen">Less Detail</span>
</button>
<div ng-show="isDetailOpen">
  <p>Per ad ferri dicta, omnis laudem dicunt duo an. Ex pri solum definitiones.</p>
</div>
```

I figured it out while working on Angular-Ionic project.