# Angular 2+ Close div with x button

Tags: html, css, angular

there is a way to close a div with an x button? In this case the div is a 'notification' that appears for a few seconds and then disappear. I don't want to use hidden because obviously the div will never appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a div by clicking a button? (SOLVED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769019/how-to-hide-a-div-by-clicking-a-button-solved)

Comment: For Angular 2+, have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549297/angular-hide-with-button)

Comment: Hmmm, no, I don't think there's a way to close a div with a X button, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *ngIf structural directive to render the div based on a boolean value. What you have to do is change the boolean value on button click.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public showNotification: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showNotification = true;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.showNotification = true;
    }, 3000);
  }

  public onCloseClick(): void {
    this.showNotification = false;
  }
}
```

---

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <div class="notification" *ngIf="showNotification">
    <div class="close" (click)="onCloseClick()">x</div>
    <div class="content">
        Some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assumed that showNotification varible is updated from a service or something. Thats why I used a setTimeInterval to update the showNotifications varible's value.

Comment: What do you mean by X button.. A button on html or keyboard X button press event?

Comment: I guess it's a HTML [X] button or something

Comment: Code sample added

Comment: Sorry guys, i was busy. I mean a x within a button. Now i'll try your solution

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use a boolean and *ngIf in your html tag ? and thus toggle it each time you want to.

here's a small example

```
<button type="button" (click)="visible = false" >x</button>
<div *ngIf="visible">
<!-- rest of your html tags here -->
</div>
```

your component :

```
export class YourComponent{
 visible:boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment

Comment: i couldn't post a comment since i didn't have enough reputation, the website usually considerates it as a comment but not this time..